# ListView with checkbox - why the checkbox doesn't show?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I'm using the ListView to provide a list for the user to choose from.

Here is the main code:

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,contacts, R.layout.list_contact,
                                          from_contacts, to_contacts);
listview_selected_contact.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
listview_selected_contact.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I wonder why the checkbox doesn't show?
The program run properly just without the visible checkbox.
Can anyone help?

Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="TextView" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:id="@+id/username"></TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think this is because you provided your own layout. show us your layout.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that your R.layout.list_contact isn't CheckedTextView.

See [source of android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_multiple_choice.xml)

I can recommend you to build custom view which is child of any ViewGroup classes and implementator of interface Checkable.

Answer (score 0):

id of `checkBox` and `listView` in `R.layout.list_contact` should be specific .

so follow ApiDemoes multiple List example for both layout and java code .