# Custom Single choice ListView

Tags: android, listview

I want to make a custom List View having Two TextViews and a radio Button in a single row. And on listitem click the radio button state should be toggle. I cannot use Simple Adapter here.

I have already asked that question [Single choice ListView custom Row Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295026/single-choice-listview-custom-row-layout) but don't find any satisfactory solution.

What I am currently doing is I am using simple_list_item_single_choice and putting data of both TextViews in a single one separated by some white spaces. But here it is getting worse (shown in the image below).

[image: http://db.tt/ulP6pn7V]

What I want is to fix the location of size and price and make list view as single choice.

XML Layout for the list can be something like:

```
**<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_size"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:width="200dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:width="70dp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>**
```

How to make custom adapter for that?

Comment: check out this tutorial http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: You can check this example in [GitHub](https://github.com/CabezasGonzalezJavier/NotifyDataSetChanged)

Comment: Check this for future reference **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s4JwU28VMko**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've been searching for an answer to this problem all morning, and the most useful thing I've found so far is [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20111205132234/http://tokudu.com/2010/android-checkable-linear-layout/).

While I haven't implemented the solution it suggests yet, it sounds like it's on the right track.

Basically, the single-choice `ListView` expects the widgets you provide it with to implement the `Checkable` interface.  `LinearLayout` and others don't. So you need to create a custom layout that inherits `LinearLayout` (or whatever layout you want to use for your items) and implements the necessary interface.

Comment: Definitely the way to go. The link has all you need, just use that class and reference it in your XML as shown.

Comment: If you want to use your own layout, f.e. with RadioButtons instead of CheckableTextView remember to set 

        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
for the button.

Answer (score 96):

I had a similar situation but fixed that easily. Try this:

1. Extend ListActivity and set your custom list adapter

   ```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //if you need title to be hidden
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_to_cart_select_service_plan);
       setListAdapter(adapter);
   }
   ```
2. Create a field to store selected index position in adapter

   ```
   int selectedIndex = -1;
   ```
3. Provide an interface to it

   ```
   public void setSelectedIndex(int index){
       selectedIndex = index;
   }
   ```
4. Set the checked state to true or false based on the selected index inside getView()

   ```
   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       RadioButton rbSelect = (RadioButton) convertView
                           .findViewById(R.id.radio1);
       if(selectedIndex == position){
       rbSelect.setChecked(true);
       }
       else{
       rbSelect.setChecked(false);
       }
   }
   ```
5. Set radio button focusable and clickable attribs to 'false'

   ```
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:checked="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false"
    />
   ```
6. Set listview descendantFocusability attrib to 'beforeDescendants'

   ```
   <ListView
       android:id="@android:id/list"
       android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
       android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
   />
   ```
7. Override onListItemClick

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
       super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
       adapter.setSelectedIndex(position);
       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
   ```

That's it..run and check

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Quick and easy to implement.

Answer (score 5):

Handled a similar issue with a **Hack (Not a perfect solution..but still works..)**

```
 listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {




                for (int i = 0; i < parent.getCount() ; i ++)
                {

                    View v = parent.getChildAt(i);
                    RadioButton radio = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.radio);
                    radio.setChecked(false);

                }

                    RadioButton radio = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radio);
                    radio.setChecked(true);



            }
        });
```

Comment: This is the best solution. Not a hack. It's simple and flawless.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `android:choiceMode` attribute of the `ListView`

```
<ListView
    ...
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the component as you like, without multiple layouts

> row_custom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:checkMark="@drawable/custom_drawable"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd" />
```

> MainActivity.java

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(context, R.layout.row_custom, mList);
```

Answer (score -1):

**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_size"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:width="200dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_price"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:width="70dp" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**

Comment: @ Chunhui :- I have throughly read that Article already but can't find desired answer.

Comment: @ Shailendra Rajawat :- Cannot get what you wanna say.

Comment: android:layout_width should not be wrap_content when you want specific width . if this replacement too can not work share the code and issue

Comment: @ Shailendra Rajawat :- That is not an issue, what I want is List View to be single choice and work properly.

Comment: by default its single choice . perhaps you did not used efficient Adapter (one with handler class) , so seeing unexpected radio buttons on . search for efficientAdapter and use it .