# Custom Listview with CheckBox single selection

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

Here I am creating custom listview with checkbox / RadioButton. I got this but I need the single selection for that.

I try using this `lstvw.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);` but it not works for me.  Is there any other solutions for that then please let me know.

main.java

```
  private ImageAdapter  adapter; 

private static String month[] = {"January","February","March","April","May",  
    "June","July","August","September",  
    "October","November","December"};  


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ListView lstvw = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

     adapter = new ImageAdapter(this, month);  
     lstvw.setAdapter(adapter);  
      lstvw.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

     lstvw.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
```

I have no idea for the how to add code for the checkbox into the adapter class.please check the adapter class as below.

ImageAdapter.class

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

public String title[];  
public String description[];  
public Activity context;  
public LayoutInflater inflater;

public ImageAdapter(Activity context,String[] title) {  
    super();  

    this.context = context;  
    this.title = title;  

    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
}  

@Override  
public int getCount() {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    return title.length;  
}  

@Override  
public Object getItem(int position) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    return null;  
}  

@Override  
public long getItemId(int position) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    return 0;  
}  

public static class ViewHolder  
{  

    TextView txtViewTitle;  

}  

@Override  
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  

    ViewHolder holder;  
    if(convertView==null)  
    {  
        holder = new ViewHolder();  
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);  

        holder.txtViewTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lstvw_textView);  
        convertView.setTag(holder);  
    }  
    else  
        holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();  

    holder.txtViewTitle.setText(title[position]);  

    return convertView;  
}   

}
```

**EDIT:**

Listitem.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lstvw_textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/itemCheckBox"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:text="hello world" />



<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/itemCheckBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="right" />
```

Comment: use RadioButton's for single selection instead of listview.

Comment: do you want to select one item only in whole list with Radio button or multiple selection with check box ?

Comment: @RDC yes i want only single item select

Comment: add listitem.xml file code...

Comment: @DhavalSodhaParmar  check the updated code with listitem.xml

Comment: your better solution is here... http://stackoverflow.com/a/10558101/1168654

Comment: @RahulPatel i have posted the answer, PL check and let me if you still have any doubt.

Comment: If you want to make a single item will show selected at a time then unchecked the existing item before checking the new one. You can simply keep the selected item position in a variable and when you click on new item then make sure the existing index item is unchecked before it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what i would do if i need to select only single item at a time.

**Home.java (Activity)**

```
package com.lvcheck.activities;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Home extends Activity 
{
    private ListView lvCheckBox;
    private Button btnCheckAll, btnClearALl;
    private String[] arr = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six"};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btnCheckAll = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCheckAll);
        btnClearALl = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClearAll);

        lvCheckBox = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvCheckBox);
        lvCheckBox.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        lvCheckBox.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, arr));


        btnCheckAll.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {           
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) 
            {
                for(int i=0 ; i < lvCheckBox.getAdapter().getCount(); i++)
                {
                    lvCheckBox.setItemChecked(i, true);             
                }
            }
        });

        btnClearALl.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {           
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                for(int i=0 ; i < lvCheckBox.getAdapter().getCount(); i++)
                {
                    lvCheckBox.setItemChecked(i, false);                
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and my **(main.xml) XML file** should like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Check All"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dip"
            android:id="@+id/btnCheckAll"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Clear All"
            android:id="@+id/btnClearAll"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lvCheckBox"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:cacheColorHint="@null"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

so the output will be like this way..

[image]

Source: [here](http://androidcodesnips.blogspot.in/2011/08/multiple-choice-list-android.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20Androidcodes%20%28AndroidCodes%29)

let me know if you have any trouble regarding this.

**Edit:** check this useful link: [Custom Single choice ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337180/custom-single-choice-listview)

Comment: Thanks, I have also done using

     "new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, arr)" 
  
But I want this using custom adapter class.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337180/custom-single-choice-listview) and [this](http://tokudu.com/2010/android-checkable-linear-layout/) link will surely help you

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CheckBox` in your adapter class. Try this.

```
   @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (convertView == null) {
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(adapterContext);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view, null);
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }

        final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        holder.name.setText(collectContactList.get(position).getName());

        holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                if (cb.isChecked() == true) 
                {
                    // Here you will get list of checked item.
                }

                else 
               {
                // Here you will get list of unchecked item.    
                }

            }
        });
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks, but I want single item selection

Comment: Have you any idea about the single selection checkbox?

Comment: inside the if condition you can get the items which is selected

Comment: Is there a multiple selection OR single? Please can you help me for that how its work?

Comment: this one is for multiple selection of items.I have not implemented it but this might help you.Read this post. http://tokudu.com/2010/android-checkable-linear-layout/