# ListView CheckBoxes not working as they should

Tags: android, listview

I have a problem by selecting CheckBoxes in my ListItems. Each ListItem has a CheckBox in it's layout and when the ListItem is clicked the CheckBox should be activated. The problem is that the CheckBoxes are randomly activated. For example: When i have 2 ListItems and click on ListItem1, it's CheckBox is activated. When i click again, CheckBox of ListItem2 is activated, too. When i click again, CheckBox of ListItem1 is deactivated. When i click again, CheckBox of ListItem2 is deactivated. When i click again it all starts from the beginning. I understand ListView reuses the Items and that i have to use getView() method, but i just can't make it work. I have to mention that I'm a bloody beginner, so please forgive me if some code doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001143/custom-listview-with-checkbox-single-selection/12003125#12003125) may help you

Comment: How can i make it work with a custom ListItem XML? That example seems only to work with a standard ListItem layout. Nonetheless it's interesting that this example isn't using getView() to make it work.

Comment: Okay so you want ListView with checkBox and Custom Array Adapter??I am trying to make a code for you hold a bit!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a Custom Array Adapter and all set.

Here is the Activity Class I created for ListView for ChekBoxList

**ActivityGamesList.java**

```
package com.rdc.gameListApp;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ActivityGamesList extends Activity {

     private ListView listGames = null; 
     private DBAdapter database = null;
     private Context context = null;    

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_of_games);

        final CheckBox favBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.favbuttonInList);
        listGames = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewGame); 

        context = getApplicationContext();
        database = new DBAdapter(context);

        //here I am getting the data from database and  putting in to List
        List<String> gamelistArrayR = database.selectAllName();     

        // custom adapter for adding fav box
        //make sure here "gamelistArrayR" is List and type is String
        listGames.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, gamelistArrayR));

        //listener for list view
        listGames.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have selected:  " +
                          position+" no row", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }

}
```

and below is the Custom Array Adapter

**CustomAdapter.java**

---

```
package com.rdc.gameListApp;

import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final List<String> values;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<String> gamelistArrayR) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_row_custom, gamelistArrayR);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = gamelistArrayR;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_custom, parent, false);

        //Game Name Text in list
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtGameNameInList);
        // Check Box in list
        CheckBox favBox = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.favbuttonInList);

        textView.setText(values.get(position));         

        //listener for check box
        favBox
        .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
                Boolean flag = isChecked;               
                if(flag){                   

                        Log.v("Debug", "step no 1");
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Marked as Favorite Game!", 1).show();                  
                }
            }
        }); 
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

and i got the output like this way..

[image]

**Edit:**

When you scroll list, the chekboxrs gets uncheked because or recreate view.

so you need to store the state of checkbox for that you should check below links

[**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309250/checkbox-gets-unchecked-on-scroll-in-a-custom-listview) So thread or
[**this**](http://www.lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html) tutorial

Comment: The code basically works, but the CheckBoxes are only highlighted when i press them. They are not selected. EDIT: My fault. I now deleted "android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" in my <ListView />. Now the code works perfect. :) Thumbs up and thanks for your help.

Comment: your welcome..really happy to see this.. :) soon i am going to create a Tutorial for this and post on my blog

Comment: Like i said, it works now, but there's another problem. When an activated CheckBox scrolls out of screen then it deactivates itself. How can i prevent this? Does ConvertView have something to do with this?

Comment: for that you need to store the state of selected CheckBox ..see Updated answer

Comment: Ok, that seems to be a little bit more complex than i thought. I'll keep working on it tomorrow and will post here if it works.

Comment: The code of the tutorial causes 2 errors. Error 1 is in this line: "list.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());" Error message: "The method setSelected(boolean) is undefined for the type String". Error 2 is in this line: "viewHolder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position));" Error message: "The method setChecked(boolean) in the type CompoundButton is not applicable for the arguments (String)". Well, "list" is an ArrayList<String>, but don't these commands only get the position in the Array?

Answer (score 0):

Try using **setOnItemSelectedListener** instead of **setOnItemClickListener** . I believe the click event is getting invoked more often that you need.

Comment: It's not working. The CheckBoxes are only highlighted when i press the ListItem, but they can't be selected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the item states in your Adapter, *not* in the View itself, because it could be a reused one, just like you say. Your call to `super.getView()` will fill in the correct text for you, but not change the checkbox state. Keep a bool array reflecting the state of each checkbox, and in getView() apply the state before returning your view:

```
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cb);
cb.setChecked(cbStates[position]);
```

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. I tried to implement it to my code, but i always get a NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION on this line: "for(int i = 0; i < cbStates.length; i++){". What am i doing wrong?