# ListView, RadioButton: correct display, but inactive

Tags: android, listview, radio-button

I have a `ListView` with own adapter: `CityZipCodesAdapter`. In the constructor I give a `List<CityZipCodesDataModel>` where I keep `String`, `String`, and `boolen` (the `RadioButton` was selected or not). This i write in `SharedPreferences` and then I read this. It all works.

```
public class CityZipCodesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CityZipCodesDataModel> {

    private final List<CityZipCodesDataModel> list;
    private final Activity context;
    private RadioButton selectedRB;

    private int selectedPosition = -1;

    public CityZipCodesAdapter(Activity context,
            List<CityZipCodesDataModel> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.city_list_item, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView cityOrZipCode;
        protected TextView listOfZipCodesInNear;
        protected RadioButton radioBtn;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.city_list_item, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.cityOrZipCode = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cityOrZipCode);
            viewHolder.listOfZipCodesInNear = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listOfZipCodesInNear);


            viewHolder.radioBtn = (RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);

        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag() ;
        }

        viewHolder.radioBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(position != selectedPosition && selectedRB != null){
                    selectedRB.setChecked(false);
                }

                selectedPosition = position;
                selectedRB = (RadioButton)v;
            }
        });


        if(selectedPosition != position){
            viewHolder.radioBtn.setChecked(false);
        }else{
            viewHolder.radioBtn.setChecked(true);
            if(selectedRB != null && viewHolder.radioBtn != selectedRB){
                selectedRB = viewHolder.radioBtn;
            }
        }

        viewHolder.listOfZipCodesInNear.setText(list.get(position).getZipCodes());
        viewHolder.cityOrZipCode.setText(list.get(position).getLocation());

        viewHolder.radioBtn.setText(list.get(position).getLocation());
        viewHolder.radioBtn.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelectedLocation());

        return view;
    }
}
```

The problem is when i turn on the application then the correct `RadioButton` is selected, but it is inactive. There is only displayed correctly.
For example,

x String1

o String2

o String3

When I click on String2 (String1 was inictialy selected) then String2 is selected, but String1 is also selected. When I click on String1, then String2 then the selection is correct.

Do you have any idea what is wrong?
Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in this part of the code:

```
if(selectedPosition != position){
        viewHolder.radioBtn.setChecked(false);
    }else{
        viewHolder.radioBtn.setChecked(true);
        if(selectedRB != null && viewHolder.radioBtn != selectedRB){
            selectedRB = viewHolder.radioBtn;
        }
    }
```

Initially `selectedPosition != position` so `selectedRB` is never set and remains null. When you click the first radio button initially, it gets set and it works but if you don't, the code doesn't unselect it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want just a single radio button to show the clickable state then you must manually remove others... what i mean is:

onclick...

```
 radio2.setChecked(true);
    radio1.setChecked(false);
     radio3.setChecked(false);
```

otherwise you set whatever you want to set but you dont cancel the others...
if they are all in the same position... it should be simple...

as far as changing other positions I dont think that what you did would work...i think after each click you need to rebuild your listview and for each position change... or use `notifyDataSetChanged()` or something like that...

found this for you

[Custom Listview with CheckBox single selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001143/custom-listview-with-checkbox-single-selection)

think it will help...