# Getting the text of selected checkbox from listview in android?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, baseadapter, android-checkbox

I am having a List view with checkBox .I want to get all the text of selected check Box from the list view .Since ,I am new to android I refer some links which uses view holder but i am not using .

```
public class EcConferenceNumber extends Activity{
    ListView checkBoxNumberListView;
    ConferenceAdapter adapter;
    Button doneBtn,cancelBtn;
    EditText profileName;
    CheckBoxListViewAdapter cbAdapter;
    static ArrayList<String> checkBoxData = null;
    String[]  myStrings;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ec_number_selection);   
        adapter = new ConferenceAdapter(this);
        checkBoxNumberListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.numberselectionlistView);

        doneBtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.donenumberbutton);
        cancelBtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelnumberbutton);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        myStrings = intent.getStringArrayExtra("strings");
    /*ArrayList<String> got=    cbAdapter.getSelectedString();

    System.out.println(""+got);*/

         checkBoxData=new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(myStrings));

        //checkBoxNumberListView.setAdapter(new CheckBoxListViewAdapter(EcConferenceNumber.this, adapter, checkBoxData));

        //System.out.println(""+checkBoxData);
          final CheckBoxListViewAdapter checkBoxListViewAdapter = new CheckBoxListViewAdapter(
                    EcConferenceNumber.this, adapter, checkBoxData);
                    checkBoxListViewAdapter.setSelectedString(new ArrayList<String>());
                    checkBoxNumberListView.setAdapter(checkBoxListViewAdapter);

            doneBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    ArrayList<String>   a=    checkBoxListViewAdapter.getSelectedString();
                    for(String b:a)
                    System.out.println("hi hi" +b);
                }
            });     


    }
    }

class CheckBoxListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<String> calendars = null;

    ArrayList<String> selectedString;
    public ArrayList<String> getSelectedString() {
        return selectedString;
    }

    public void setSelectedString(ArrayList<String> selectedString) {
        this.selectedString = selectedString;
    }

    LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public CheckBoxListViewAdapter(Activity activity, ConferenceAdapter adapter, ArrayList<String> checkBoxData) {
        this.calendars = checkBoxData;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return calendars.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
final Context c = null;

        View vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ec_checkbox_number, null);

        TextView cbTV = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.checkboxtextView);
        final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

        cbTV.setText(calendars.get(position));


        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    selectedString.add(checkBox.getText().toString());
                }else{
                    selectedString.remove(checkBox.getText().toString());
                }


            }

        });

        return vi;
    }


}
```

I am getting error while selecting the checkbox .I want to store all the selected check box text.

ec_number_selection.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/meetingprofilename"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Profile Name:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/meetingprofilename"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/meetingprofilename"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/meetingprofilename"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancelnumberbutton"
        android:layout_width="158dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText2"
        android:text="Cancel" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/donenumberbutton"
        android:layout_width="158dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cancelnumberbutton"
        android:text="Done" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/numberselectionlistView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/cancelnumberbutton"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

ec_checkBox_number.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/checkboxtextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="107dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

error log

```
10-22 12:03:27.950: E/AndroidRuntime(25520): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-22 12:03:27.950: E/AndroidRuntime(25520): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-22 12:03:27.950: E/AndroidRuntime(25520):    at com.bambeeq.conferencecall.CheckBoxListViewAdapter$1.onCheckedChanged(EcConferenceNumber.java:109)
10-22 12:03:27.950: E/AndroidRuntime(25520):    at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:137)
10-22 12:03:27.950: E/AndroidRuntime(25520):    at android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle(CompoundButton.java:92)
10-22 12:03:27.950: E/AndroidRuntime(25520):    at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:104)
10-22 12:03:27.950: E/AndroidRuntime(25520):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17420)
10-22 12:03:27.950: E/AndroidRuntime(25520):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
10-22 12:03:27.950: E/AndroidRuntime(25520):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-22 12:03:27.950: E/AndroidRuntime(25520):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-22 12:03:27.950: E/AndroidRuntime(25520):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
10-22 12:03:27.950: E/AndroidRuntime(25520):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-22 12:03:27.950: E/AndroidRuntime(25520):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-22 12:03:27.950: E/AndroidRuntime(25520):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
10-22 12:03:27.950: E/AndroidRuntime(25520):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
10-22 12:03:27.950: E/AndroidRuntime(25520):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I got struct here.Any answer will be help full

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18162931/android-get-selected-item-using-checkbox-in-listview-when-i-click-a-button. check this if it helps

Answer (score 2):

your didn't init selectedString - you need to initialize it - it is null when the onchange event is triggered, init it in the constructor.

```
selectedString = new ArrayList<String>();
```

or call the setSelectedString function.

Comment: You beat me to it. Though it should be

    `selectedString = new ArrayList<String>();`

no?

Comment: i intialized it in the constructor

Comment: @user2841300, no you initialized calenders, and your using selectedString in the event...

Comment: so i what i have to do now

Comment: i am getting null values

Answer (score 1):

You are not settimg the object `selectedString`
First initialize it in your `Adapetr` class or directly set it from your `Activity`.

IN your Activty class change code like this..

```
    CheckBoxListViewAdapter checkBoxListViewAdapter = new CheckBoxListViewAdapter(
    EcConferenceNumber.this, adapter, checkBoxData);
    checkBoxListViewAdapter.setSelectedString(new ArrayList<String>());
    checkBoxNumberListView.setAdapter(checkBoxListViewAdapter);
```

And call this method to get the selected string data list to your activity..

```
checkBoxListViewAdapter.getSelectedString();
```

Comment: i have created new object for Arraylist inside getview() is it correct?

Comment: Dont try to initilize in the getview() because it calls multiple times try init in your adapter constructor.then there is only object..

Comment: i want to use this selectedString in EcSelectedNumber.java class how can i do that?

Comment: i have updated your code where can  i get the values of selected check boxes

Comment: it is returning null values ya..doneBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     ArrayList<String> a=    checkBoxListViewAdapter.getSelectedString();
     for(String b:a)
     System.out.println("hi hi" +b);
    }
   });

Answer (score 1):

use this way :

```
  mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
  {
   @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
{
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_id);
}
});
```

also use with converview.setonClicklistener in Adapter.

just change CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) converview.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_id);

Comment: i have to use this in adapter or activity

Comment: setOnItemClickListener in Activity.

Comment: if u wan to use in ADAPTER use in getview()method like convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         }

   });

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19027843/android-get-text-of-all-checked-checkboxes-in-listview

Answer (score 1):

initialize string array 'myStrings' with new operator or create a string list.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using custom `listview` you can achieve in the following manner.Use oncheckChangedListener in the getView method of adapter class.

```
myCheck.setOncheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckchangedListener(){
           public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton btn,boolean isChecked)
    {
          if(isChecked){
               // here you can get the text of selected check box
            }
       }
  });
```

Let me know if you need any other info.

Comment: Can you update your code b'coz I am not able to see the updates?

Comment: have a look at this link this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/12001363/704374

Comment: i did not know how to store the value .do you have any idea

Comment: you can store the it in the arraylist with the position and retrieve it back.