# Android : At a time only one item isChecked in listview with checkboxes

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have a Custom `ListView` that contains `checkbox` and `TextView' per row. I want to set it up so that only one checkbox can be selected at a time.... **Thanks in Advance** .

Comment: You would need to uncheck the other boxes manually.

Comment: Use Single Choice Mode for ListView. **setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);**

Comment: Have a Java model for your rows which holds the checked status. Check or unCheck it if relevant row is checked. Also uncheck all other rows. Then notifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: Code snippet would be really helpful .... thnxs

Answer (score 1):

if you are using this default class

```
mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, mData);
```

then you can use

```
setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

or if you are using any custom class then set this as follow.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;

holder.mCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

holder.mCheckBox.setTag(position);
        holder.mCheckBox
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                            boolean isChecked) {
                                                 // do your stuff here.
                    }
                });
```

this will allow you to click only single check-box,

Comment: Which code you are using `simple_list_item_multiple_choice` or custom adapter.

Comment: Okay, or you have created your own layout or you are using android default XML files.

Comment: Then Use second method which i have defined in above code, what's the problem you are facing?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48927/discussion-between-ryderz-and-innocentkiller)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i would do if i need to select only single item at a time.

**Home.java (Activity)**

```
package com.lvcheck.activities;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Home extends Activity 
{
    private ListView lvCheckBox;
    private Button btnCheckAll, btnClearALl;
    private String[] arr = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six"};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btnCheckAll = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCheckAll);
        btnClearALl = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClearAll);

        lvCheckBox = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvCheckBox);
        lvCheckBox.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        lvCheckBox.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, arr));


        btnCheckAll.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {           
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) 
            {
                for(int i=0 ; i < lvCheckBox.getAdapter().getCount(); i++)
                {
                    lvCheckBox.setItemChecked(i, true);             
                }
            }
        });

        btnClearALl.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {           
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                for(int i=0 ; i < lvCheckBox.getAdapter().getCount(); i++)
                {
                    lvCheckBox.setItemChecked(i, false);                
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and my (main.xml) XML file should like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Check All"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dip"
            android:id="@+id/btnCheckAll"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Clear All"
            android:id="@+id/btnClearAll"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lvCheckBox"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:cacheColorHint="@null"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

so the output will be like this way..
[image]

Source: [here](http://androidcodesnips.blogspot.in/2011/08/multiple-choice-list-android.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20Androidcodes%20%28AndroidCodes%29)

let me know if you have any trouble regarding this.

Edit: check this useful link: [Custom Single choice ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337180/custom-single-choice-listview)