# Sparse array as single choice ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have the following data retrieved from server:

```js
[
  {id: 8, name: "Item1"},
  {id: 14, name: "Item2"},
  {id: 30, name: "Item3", active: true},
  {id: 42, name: "Item4"}
]
```

I want to put that data into single choice ListView (in Dialog, using `setSingleChoiceItems()`) and after user makes his choice, send the item id back to the server.

How to do that? Only solution I figured out is to use some helper array which keeps mapping between list items (which AFAIK has to go in sequence) and item ids (which are pretty much random). I also tried using some Adapters, but didn't figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

Make your own custom ListView and override the getView to show whatever you want in each row. You will need a ViewHolder class to extract the custom row list views that you have made. Have a look at this:

[Single choice ListView custom Row Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295026/single-choice-listview-custom-row-layout)

Answer (score 0):

Here example use single choice listview to you:

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
     <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview1"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:fadingEdge="vertical"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
        android:dividerHeight="1px"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity:

```
    String[] items = new String[] { "Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4" };
    int[] itemsIds = new int[] { 8, 14, 30, 42 };
    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview1);
    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, android.R.id.text1, items));
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            //here send your item id itemsIds[position]
        }
    });
```

Comment: if send item id event onItemSelected() to you need, then use onItemSelectedListener()